# Detect multiple faces using Dlib's face detector using python

Tags: python, image, dlib

The following is the code used to detect single face in a image but the issue is if there are multiple faces in a image it takes only first one. Pls suggest

```
import caffe, dlib, io
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
img21 = 'group.jpg'
im_name = img21
img = io.imread(os.path.join('./',im_name))
faces=[]
faces= detector(img)
total= len(faces)
print('total faces here :',total)
cropped_face = input_image_cropped[faces[0].top():faces[0].bottom(),
faces[0].left():faces[0].right(), :]
input_image_cropped = caffe.io.load_image(os.path.join('./', im_name))  
cropped_face = input_image_cropped[faces[0].top():faces[0].bottom(), 
faces[0].left():faces[0].right(), :]
h = faces[0].bottom() - faces[0].top()
w = faces[0].right() - faces[0].left()
age_prediction_cropped = age_net.predict([cropped_face])
print('\n\t   predicted age (Dlib-cropped image):',
age_prediction_cropped[0].argmax())
plt.show()
```

FYI:
i stripped other parts of the code which is not required.

I gone thru the below link but i could not run the  loop for all the detected faces ?  pls suggest how can i run the loop for all detected faces.
http://dlib.net/face_detector.py.html

Answer (score 0):

With the following change the issue is resolved

for i, d in enumerate(faces):
        cropped_face = input_image_cropped[ d.top():d.bottom(), d.left():d.right(), :]
        input_image_cropped = caffe.io.load_image(os.path.join('./', im_name))
        cropped_face = input_image_cropped[d.top():d.bottom(), d.left():d.right(), :]